# En un plis plas context

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I have read previous  posts about the origin of the expression," en un plis plas".

I also have checked the RAE and Spanish Dictionary ,and Word Reference  for examples. They all confirm it means to do something quickly or if something happens quickly.It is a synonym for "en un santiámen".
I asked my Spanish friend if it can be used in the following sentence and she said no but I can't understand why.

" En un plis plas,un carterista le robó el dinero y el móvil sigilosamente en un barrio destartalado."
I thought it would fit fine like the English :in the blink of an eye ,in a flash or in a jiffy. It seems strange to me is my friend correct?

Answer (score 1):

Si es correcto, aunque no es lo más usual colocarlo al comienzo de la frase (I know English grammar is different).

> En un barrio destartalado, un carterista le robó el dinero y el móvil sigilosamente en un plis plas.

By the way, the word "destartalado" is more common in objects, not in neighborhoods. Instead:

> Un barrio decadente
> Un barrio desfavorecido

Comment: Thank you and for the clarification on yhe vocabulary.